# How to add horizontal line between text elements

Tags: html, css, frontend, web-frontend

I am trying to add a line between two text elements, like the picture below in HTML, but I cannot. I can only add a line between "Training Program" and the other text will be in the next line.

```css
h3 {
    position: relative;
}

h3 span {
    background-color: white;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

h3:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 0.5em;
    width: 60%;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h3 style="font-family:Montserrat"><span>Training program</span></h3>
<h3 style="font-family:Montserrat; text-align:right; margin-top:10px"><span>Read more</span></h3>
```

I want to add a line like this picture. Can anybody help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox to do this easily.

```css
h3{
  font-family:Montserrat
}
.flex-parent{display:flex;}
.line-div{
  flex: 1; /* flex-grow */
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.the-line{
  height: 50%;
  border-bottom:1px solid #bbb;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
  <h3><span>Training program</span></h3>
  <div class="line-div"><div class="the-line"></div></div>
  <h3><span>Read more</span></h3>
</div>
```

### References:

[Excellent flexbox cheatsheet](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/#align-items)

[Excellenter *short* Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k32voqQhODc)

Comment: I'd agree that flexbox is a good approach to this. Why use actual elements like this: `<div class="line-div"><div class="the-line"></div></div>`, though? Wouldn't one or more _pseudo-elements_ represent a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with **flexbox**, you just need to play around a bit more.

But here is a quick snippet:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

h3 {
  font-family:Montserrat;
}

.line {
  height: 0;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  width: 40%;

}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <h3>Training program</h3>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <h3><span>Read more</span></h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There will be multiple ways to achieve this effect, but one way is to contain the two `<h3>` elements inside a `<div>` which you then apply a `border-bottom` to.

Then, when you push the headings lower than they would normally appear (using the vertical translation `transform: translateY()`) the `border-bottom` will now appear to run inbetween the two headings, rather than running along beneath them.

**Working Example:**

```css
.heading-group {
display: flow-root;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(191, 191, 191);
}

.heading {
 padding: 0 6px;
 background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 transform: translateY(27px);
}

.training {
 float: left;
}

.read-more {
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading-group">
<h3 class="heading training">Training program</h3>
<h3 class="heading read-more">Read more</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use hr tags for putting horizontal rows in between your html texts.